# Rails 3.1 rc4 problem with mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, passenger, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mysql2

I just installed passenger (apache2) on my ubuntu server to deploy my rails 3.1 rc4 rails app into the wild, and wanted to change from sqlite to mysql.

I installed the necessary ubuntu packages

I updated my Gemfile with the recommended:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

And updated my database.yml file

```
production:
adapter: mysql2
database: database
username: deploy
password: (***blocked for security reasons***)
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

When I try to create the production database with rake:

rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=”production” --trace

It gives me a bunch of crazy errors

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
”production” database is not configured
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-     3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:62:in `establish_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
(And so on)
```

I have tried install the regular mysql gem, which also didn't work.  I have also tried <0.3 of mysql2, but that seemed to lead to an error being thrown complaining about using versions 0.2 with rails 3.1 rc4

I am really stumped :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried without the quotes around "production" ?

RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate